# Difference between including files from single and multiple CDN providers

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

Currently, I've included my files from **Google**, **Bootstrap CDN** and **jsDelivr**:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome-css'  href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.min.js'></script>
```

It's always pop up in my mind that **Google** is the most suitable source for jQuery and **Bootstrap CDN** for bootstrap, but **jsDelivr** supports all of them, should I just import those files from **jsDelivr** instead?

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome-css'  href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.min.js'></script>
```

Is there any significant difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

why should including css/js via cdn be a good solution? just reduce yourself to one css and one js since it's pretty easy in your case. The result will be a faster page-load and no dependency on some internet-resources > The page will be available even when offline

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of using multiple CDN:s is bypassing the browser's concurrent connection limit, since it's limited by server.

Some stats: 
[Max parallel http connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)

On the other hand, using Google CDN, you run the possibility of the files already being cached in the user's browser, since using Google CDN is a fairly common practice.